# Compiler cannot find header file within header file in C++

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, yaml-cpp

I have a header file provided by yaml-cpp library, yaml.h

yaml.h:

```
#include "yaml-cpp/parser.h"
#include "yaml-cpp/emitter.h"
#include "yaml-cpp/emitterstyle.h"
#include "yaml-cpp/stlemitter.h"
#include "yaml-cpp/exceptions.h"

#include "yaml-cpp/node/node.h"
#include "yaml-cpp/node/impl.h"
#include "yaml-cpp/node/convert.h"
#include "yaml-cpp/node/iterator.h"
#include "yaml-cpp/node/detail/impl.h"
#include "yaml-cpp/node/parse.h"
#include "yaml-cpp/node/emit.h"
```

main.cpp

```
#include "./lib/yaml-cpp/include/yaml.h"

int main()
{
    YAML::Node config = YAML::LoadFile("config.yaml");
    return 0;
    
}
```

All the header files are in the same directory `(/home/user/application/libs/yaml-cpp/include)`, but the compiler is unable to find parser.h and all the other includes. Why is this so and how do I fix it?

I have tried using `g++ -I/home/user/application/libs/yaml-cpp/include main.cpp` but that did not work.

I am on a linux environment. Everything works fine when the header files are kept in /usr/lib64, but I am not allowed to do that for this project.

Comment: Does the path to the header files start with a "/"? Your pseudo code looks like that. Are you on a platform where such a path indicates an absolut path? Is that on purpose? Or do you instead want a relative path which starts with "path/to..."?

Comment: @Yunnosch I have updated the question with more information. the header is provided by a third party lib and in their header code they have a hardcoded path for the other header files.

Comment: Your pseudo code is riskily omitting relevant info. Does the "hardcoded path for the other header files" absolute"? Does it end in "/lib"? Consider doing less of "anonymisation" by creating a [mre] with precise but non-personal information. If necessary reinstall to change too personal paths. Please [edit] to collect all info in the question itself instead of splitting it between question body and comments down here. Consider making a [mre] with the same problem but without the library, to simplify debugging. I.e. simulate a similar library. Probably header-only is sufficient.

Comment: @Yunnosch I've updated the question. I thought it would be easier to understand without the extra information but apparently not. Please let me know if the updated question is clearer

Comment: Are you sure that the headers are inside "yaml-cpp/include" and the include lines list them as `#include "yaml-cpp/parser.h"`, i.e. do NOT look for them inside a "include" folder? I really recommend to create a [mre] with a self-created header-only-library. It would allow you to experiment with different installation file structures, include lines ... It would also make reproducing your problem easier for potential answerers. Apart from the fact that making a MRE is simply a good way for yourself to trace the relevant detials of your problem.

Comment: yes that's right. #include yaml-cpp/parser.h came with the header file by default. yaml-cpp/include is where I need the compiler to look for the header files

Comment: "yaml-cpp/include is where I need the compiler to look for the header files" What makes you think that, if the headers are not there?

Comment: I'm not saying that the compiler is looking for header files in yaml-cpp/include. Im saying that's where the header files are located. I'm not sure where else to put my header files. The project structure was provided by my company

Comment: Sorry. I seem to have misread somethign. Still, can you create a MRE which can be reproduced by potential answerers?

Comment: Do you have a file at this path `/home/user/application/libs/yaml-cpp/include/yaml-cpp/parser.h` ? If not, what do you expect the combination of `#include "yaml-cpp/parser.h"` and `-I/home/user/application/libs/yaml-cpp/include` to do?

Comment: Yes I have the file there @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.

Comment: Have you checked carefully for typos in your paths, remember that Linux paths are case sensitive?

Comment: Please *copy and paste from the terminal* both your `ls` command with its full output and your `g++` command with its full output, unedited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have a file `yaml.h` that itself includes other files like this:

```
#include "yaml-cpp/parser.h"
```

Then the expected directory layout is as follows:

```
somewhere/
  |
  +-- yaml.h
  |
  +-- yaml-cpp/
        |
        +-- parser.h
```

You are expected to pass `-Isomewhere` to your compiler and use the header file `yaml.h` like this in your own source code:

```
#include <yaml.h>
```